# Xml formatting lost on download

Tags: c#, xml

I have a table which contains a column of type XML in sql.

I'm using entity framework to fetch this record.

```
XmlString = XmlData.XML_DTA;
```

**XML which is stored in this column is saved with formatting in one of the tag** for eg.

```
Existing documents are:

 - ABCDEFGH: USD12yhr56yhf
 - XYZ: nr65756hgfh
```

After fetching the column value I download this content as follows.

```
return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(XmlString), MediaTypeNames.Text.Xml, FileName);
```

**Now the problem is that the file which gets downloaded shows the content without formatting** like this

```
Existing documents are:- ABCDEFGH: USD12yhr56yhf- XYZ: nr65756hgfh
```

**Is there any way I can keep the formatting in the dowloaded xml file?**

Comment: **with** formatting, you mean linebreaks? How do you display the text where you noticed it lost these? Are you sure the linebreaks are really gone from the string and that it isn't just a display issue? Have you verified the downloaded file, what that contains? What I mean is, have you downloaded it as a file directly to disk and looked at it? Or are you looking at it after some kind of library has parsed the contents and extracted the string? I ask because you show the code that serves the file, but not the code that extracts the string.

Comment: yes sir, by formatting i mean line breaks. After downloading, if i open the file with notepad++, I can see the value has line breaks but if I open it in internet explorer the formatting is not rendered. and also xml tags in notepad ++ are in single line